Error running R code for vector auto regression - analyzing macroeconomic factors
I am someone who does not know R or any other programming language at all and I have been dependent on CHAT-GPT for the codes. I am facing an issue while running a code.
I have a panel data in the following structure:

The data in the image has a total of 15466 rows and there is data from 5 countries (France, Germany, UK, USA and Japan) I am trying to run a vector auto regression model on the above panel data with Excess returns, GDP growth, GDP per capita growth, Inflation rate and Interest rate.
The image of the code I have run (sourced from Chat GPT is below) using the library panelvar and the pvargmm function:

I have already checked and none of my data set is missing. however I am encountering the below error:

i have obviously been trying to fix this error using chatgpt but i do not know how to fix this? Does anyone know how to fix this? or does anyone have a code for vector autoregression that actually works properly?
my data seems to be okay.I do not have missing values in the 5 variables that I am using (excess returns, gdp growth, gdp per capita growth, inflation rate and  interest rates). there are duplicate data as some companies have multiple ISINs (I have used ISINs as an identifier to make the calculations) hence have used ISIN and years as panel identifiers.
How do I fix this?

"result" seems to be the internal list containing the estimation results. I took a quick look at the source code and it looks like the "result" list will not be created unless you set the steps parameter (eg.  steps = c("twostep")) in the pvargmm function. Try to do that and see if it helps. Otherwise, consider asking this quesion on stackoverflow instead. :-)

@Pleb it did work. thank you! but I have a couple of more questions: no matter how much I reduce the lag and also reduce the instruments - the hansen test gives me this error - "Hansen test of overid. restrictions: chi2(16) = 1425.6 Prob > chi2 = 0
(Robust, but weakened by many instruments.)" how do I fix this?

I don't really know the package tbh. The best thing you can do, is to post this as another question, but on Stackoverflow instead. I believe the package is not maintained and might contain some errors. Alternatively, you can look through the source code of the package and try to figure out why you get the error (even though it might be hard since you are a beginner to programming). I wish you the best of luck! :-)
